# How do I make a mobile-friendly popup on my website?

Tags: asp.net, html, mobile-website

Is there a simple way to trigger a mobile OS's native pop-up/alert/etc. from some form of web code? I'm writing an ASP.NET mobile web page and I'd like to, for example, have the iPhone's UIAlertView appear.

EDIT: What I'm looking for is not the method with which to detect which mobile browser is accessing the site (I already know how to do that). If the code to trigger a pop-up that will look nice in an Android browser is different than the code to trigger a pop-up that will look nice in an iPhone browser, I can simply throw in a switch statement that redirects the user to the pop-up that corresponds with their browser. I'm trying to find the html/javascript/asp.net code which will create a mobile-friendly pop-up, either in general or for the various popular mobile web browsers specifically.

Comment: Have you tried the javascript `alert()` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know whether there is any pre-built functionality in .NET that can achieve this, but you can surely write one yourself.

You can write a method, that returns the code for your popup, based on the user OS (simple switch statement should do).

**EDIT** *after taking a short nap*:

I believe you should reconsider using popups. They are quite annoying even on desktop browsers and many people block them automatically. Probably every blog about accessibility will tell you, that you should keep mobile version of your website as simple as possible because of various compatibility issues that you can run into.

Instead, try to think about some interesting way to incorporate messages for users in a different and appealing way, that won't disturb anybody.

Comment: The idea was that I had/have a mobile web site as well as a native mobile app which provides more functionality than the site. I wanted to have a pop-up appear when you visit the site from a mobile device, notifying the user that there is a mobile app available. However, after trying this out it does look clunky and annoying and there are I suppose better ways to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

What I do is use a div popup (that floats ontop of the page) and eighter make a big close button or set at timeout to remove it.
jquery mobile is a good place to start.